# Should I use airflow upgradedb when upgrading the postgresql version?

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I am planning on upgrading the postgresql database from 9.5 to either 9.6 or 12+. But the Airflow version will remain the same (1.10.12)
Is there any reason to run the airflow upgradedb command or is that needed only when upgrading the actual airflow version?

Comment: Offtopic: Version 9.6, why? Next year it's EOL, just like your 9.5 version will be in the next couple of days. I'm not a fan of upgrading each year, I would make the step to version 12 or maybe 13.

Answer (score 1):

`airflow upgradedb` or `airflwo initdb` is only needed when upgrading Airflow version not DB version.

`airflow upgradedb` command should be idempotent and safe to run multiple times anyways too.

Answer (score 0):

`upgradedb` does not upgrade your PostgreSQL version. It upgrades the schema of the metadata database using migration scripts. You can see the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ffb472cf9e630bd70f51b74b0d0ea4ab98635572/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py#L45)